# No field mConstructorArgs in class Landroid/view/LayoutInflater in Android Q

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

One of the massive projects I am helping with uses MvvmCross v6.1.2 When we target the framework Android 10.0 (API Level 29) (Q), as soon as the OnCreate() lifecycle function of the MainActivity runs, an exception crash happens on the line SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main).

Show Below Error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mConstructorArgs in class Landroid/view/LayoutInflater; (declaration of 'android.view.LayoutInflater' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)

Comment: [Related github issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3550), Seems like it fixed in `v6.4.1`

Comment: Hey Adil! Please see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078153/mvvmcross-android-10-0-q-mainactivity-exception-crash-on-setcontentview/59558389

Answer (score 3):

(I posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078153/mvvmcross-android-10-0-q-mainactivity-exception-crash-on-setcontentview/59558389) as well) I asked the question to the creators and maintainers of the MVVMCross framework on Twitter, as you can see in [this thread](https://twitter.com/Saamerm/status/1199748710080622593).
I got the following response:

> You need 6.4.1. No known workarounds maybe except for copying all
> the necessary code to fix that layout inflater issue.

This means that the only solution to target the framework Android 10.0 and above is to update to package version 6.4.1 or up. It is a very difficult process, since among other things, it also requires updating the Solution to .NET Core 2.0 Framework.

What does that mean? As of 2019, the Android Play Store only accepts APK files that are targeting framework 8.1. So by November 2020, they are changing the requirement to Android 10.0, by when you will need to update your nuget package as well.

Update: I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/dev-genius/oldmvvmcrossxamarinsolutionstheloomingandroid10deadline-1744a54b6dbd?source=friends_link&sk=fb688eb94d4a38e3b73dd7d10b04fa74) about this as well to raise awareness about this issue, since there's a deadline of November 2020 before which users must target their apps to Android 10.

Update2: If you were publishing a new app, or if you had to republish your app with a different bundle Id and name, then your deadline has already passed as Sasha stated

Update 3: I [wrote another article](https://prototypemakers.medium.com/migrating-updating-an-old-xamarin-native-mvvmcross-project-c2ddd90282b6) to show people step by step instructions on how to update/migrate to the latest MvvmCross

Comment: For developers releasing a new app the deadline was July 2020.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my Answer